# Storing multi dimensional array in Variable. Is this valid?

Tags: python

After some research, I am giving more accurate information on my question.  How to get items from a dictionary that has list and dictionary again within that list?

```
{
'stationary': [
{
'pencil': 'Dixon', 
'eraser': 'Staples', 
'marker': 'Sharpie'
}
]
}
```

Comment: `['stationary'][0]['pencil']` is not valid Python. What exactly do you expect that to be?

Comment: stationary:Array

Comment: And what is "stationary:Array"? That's not python either.

Comment: Here is my goal that I am trying to achieve with this code. I have a JSON file with keys like below:
{
"stationary" : [ {
    "pencil" : "dixon",
    "eraser" : "stabples",
    "marker": "sharpie"
    }]
}

this JSON file is ingested into DB, when it does, this whole statonary is stored as a Array list. But in JSON its not an array. And i have to verify if the JSON file matches whats ingested.

Comment: I modified my question, please take a look again.

Answer (score 2):

I think the var2 should be: `[['stationary',0,'pencil'],['stationary',0,'eraser'],['stationary',0,'marker']]`

Comment: I am getting KeyError whenI try this.

Comment: I modified my question, please take a look again.